# How can I break as soon as a line of code matches a regex in the Perl debugger?

Tags: perl, debugging, watch

I know I can add watches for variables as well as expressions with the `w` command, is it possible to tell it to simply parse each command and stop if a certain piece of text is in that command?

Something like `w m/bad command/` where `$_` is a string containing the next command that is being executed.

I'm working with Komodo on Windows doing remote CGI debugging right now, but I can also use `perl -d` on a linux shell.

---

**Update**:

I'll try to make this clearer. There's a file with data on disk being deleted, and I don't know where. The program I'm debugging consists of a lot of .pl files being required into each other, and the complete codebase is even larger. I could of course grep through this for either the part of the data files' name (I know the extension), or for `unlink`. But since I don't know which code files are being used by my program, that does not get me very far.

Let's consider this piece of code, which is going to be debugged:

```
if ($foo == 1) {
  unlink 'filename.example';
}
```

Now when I'm debugging this, **I'd like the debugger to stop if the next perl command (from the script) which is about to be executed contains `/example/`**. I want kind of a hook that is run before the execution of the next command.

That way, I don't need to know *where* (as in which line or file) the thing I'd like to break at is, nor do I need a variable name (as there is none).

I know this is weird to explain, but I thought it might be a common problem. Maybe there's another approach altogether?

Comment: What do you mean by "command"?

Comment: @BillRuppert I do not mean a variable. I want to find out where a data file is being deleted from disk. There is no variable involved and I don't know where in my ~20 source files this happens. I'll adjust the question.

Comment: For those lurkers who want to know how to watch a variable for changes, see this question instead: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21339489/247696

Comment: Pretty neat edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am unaware of a module that does exactly what you want, but [Devel::Trace](https://metacpan.org/module/Devel%3a%3aTrace) is a very small module (20 lines of code) that prints every line before it is executed.

You could create a subclass of that, and modify the DB::DB subroutine to set $DB::single = 1 if the code matches your desired string.

See [brian d foy's post](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2011/11/trace-your-perl-programs/) about Devel::Trace for a more thorough description, with examples.

Answer (score 5):

Watch points are set with the 'w' command:

```
 BD<1>  w  $cannonballs
```

will break the program every time $cannonballs changes.

```
 BD<1> w $i == 19
```

will break when the value at $i is set to 19. For example

```
 $ cat  foo.pl 

 foreach $i ( 0..100 ) {
    print "$i\n";
 }

 $ perl -d foo.pl

 Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.28 Editor support available.

 Enter h or `h h' for help, or `man perldebug' for more help.

 main::(foo.pl:2):       foreach $i ( 0..100 ) {   
   DB<1> w $i == 3   
   DB<2> c 
 0 
 1 
 2 
 Watchpoint 0:   $i == 3 changed:
     old value:  ''
     new value:  '1' 
 main::(foo.pl:3):          print "$i\n";   
   DB<2> p $i 
 3   
   DB<3> q 
 Watchpoint 0:   $i == 3 changed:
     old value:  '1'
     new value:  '' 
   DB<3> q
 $
```

You'll probably want to use the full namespace of the variable, otherwise you'll get breaks any time any variable with the same name come into or goes out of scope.

Comment: I accidentally upvoted this, but it's not actually an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The debugger already can do that (well, almost). It is not called a *watch expression*, though, it is called a *breakpoint*.

You can set a breakpoint to a line and condition:

```
b 33 /pattern/i
```

You have to specify the line number, though. See [Perl debugging](http://p3rl.org/perldebug).

Comment: I know I can set breakpoints. What I don't know is the line number. Or the file. That's why I want it to parse every command and stop if it contains the action I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a break point in code using

```
$DB::single = 1;
```

To use a break point in a watch configuration, enclose the break in a conditional that matches what you want to watch.

In your case:

```
if ( $command =~ /example/ ) {
    $DB::single = 1;
}
```

should serve.

Answer (score -1):

Check out [`Tie::Trace`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tie%3a%3aTrace), which can alert you of the locations that a variable's value is changed. I suppose you could even hack it with `$DB::single=1` expressions to break in the debugger every time a variable's value changes.

Comment: While this is good to know, it doesn't really help with my problem. Thanks anyway!