# How can I watch for changes to an expression in the Perl debugger?

Tags: perl, debugging, watch

With the Perl debugger, I know I can set breakpoints at certain lines of code with the `b` command. Can I get the debugger to stop as soon as the contents of a variable has changed?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can create watch points using the `w` command in the Perl debugger.

## Crash course on the `w` debugger command:

Create a watch-expression by typing `w` and then an expression that will monitored for changes:

```
DB<1> w $variablename
```

Enter `c` to continue until the watched expression changes. Once you do, you will get output similar to this:

```
DB<2> c
Watchpoint 0:   $variablename changed:
    old value:  ''
    new value:  'hi'
main::(ex.pl:6):    $variablename = "";
```

Note that **the debugger stops at the statement after the changed has happened**, so the line displayed might not be relevant at all.

Also note that the expression is **stringified**. So for example, changing a variable to `undef` will give you this output:

```
  DB<2> c
Watchpoint 0:   $variablename changed:
    old value:  'hi'
    new value:  ''
main::(ex.pl:7):    $variablename = undef;
```

If the variable is subsequently changed to an empty string, the debugger will not stop, as **a stringified empty string and a stringified undef is considered equal**.

If the watch expression is a list, the debugger will compare the stringified elements of the list:

```
  DB<1> w $variablename, "second"

  DB<2> c
Watchpoint 0:   $variablename, "second" changed:
    old value:  'one', 'second'
    new value:  'two', 'second'
main::(hi.pl:6):    $variablename = "three";
```

You can use array variables or hash variables as watch-expressions, and they will be treated as any other list.

To delete a watch-expression, use the `W` command, and to view a list of active watch-expressions, use the `L` command.

## Tip: Use temporary global variables

Since the watch-expression is re-evaluated with every statement, you can't expect a watch-expression that uses a lexical variable to work out of scope. A quick tip is to create a global reference to the lexical, and track that instead:

```
DB<1> $main::my_debug_variable = $hashref_lexical_variable

DB<2> w $main::my_debug_variable->{key_im_watching}
```

## Tip: Use `Data::Dumper`

Use `Data::Dumper` to watch the contents of a non-scalar:

```
DB<1> w Data::Dumper->Dump([$hashref])
```

This is preferable to a simple `w $hashref`, because it will stop when the values of the hash change, rather than simply the address the reference is pointing (since a hashref stringifies to something like `HASH(0x2a07a90)`).

Comment: the last two tips are great!

Comment: Another tip: `w $$` breaks on entry into forked children

Comment: In [Programming Perl](https://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=9780596004927) (4th edition, third release, 2013-12-13), "w" is claimed to list source code, the same as in the first edition, 1991 (it seems to be 'v' now (Perl version 5.30)). That is one month before this answer was written. When did it change from 'w' to 'v'? With Perl 5 in 1994?

Comment: OK, I found it. According to the documentation, 'w' was reassigned to watch-expressions in [Perl version 5.7.3](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/JHI/perl-5.7.3/pod/perldebug.pod) (2002-03-05). In [Perl version 5.7.2](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/JHI/perl-5.7.2/pod/perldebug.pod) (2001-07-13) 'w' is still for source listing. It is the book that is ***seriously out of date*** wrt. to the Perl debugger (nearly 10 years out of date at the time of publication (February 2012) for the edition that should have it (the 4th Edition)).

Comment: Thanks @PeterMortensen . Feel free to edit my answer to update it.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you can use `"ddd your_script.pl&"` in the Linux, and watch variables like C/C++ debugger do in GUI.